# select the max number of features that occurs with N rows using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a database that contains 37000 rows and 100 features.

The DB has a lot of Nan values.

But the big problem is that if feature A occurs with 600 rows and feature B occurs with 700 rows, the common rows between them may be only 10 rows.

I wanna find the max number of features that occurs with N rows at least

Example:
Input Database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku0P8.png)

out: where N=5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKb0t.png)

Comment: Use `df = df.dropna().dropna(axis=1)`

Comment: If need filter then `N` rows use `df = df.dropna().dropna(axis=1).head(N)`

Comment: In fact this is not the solution for my problem. Because all rows contain nan values and all columns contain nan values. So if I used dropna, I will get an empty dataframe

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.